# Set browser locale in headless chrome with python

Tags: python, browser, selenium-chromedriver, locale, headless

I'm running headless chrome with python script, from docker container. Browser is opening in local language, instead of the language I have specified within the code.

I am using experimental option, but it doesn't work.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
```

This doesn't work either:

```
options.add_argument('--lang=es')
```

Or this:

```
browser_locale = 'en'
options.add_argument("--lang={}".format(browser_locale))
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I found the solution to be this:

In my `create_driver` method, I added `self.driver.get("https://www.google.com/ncr")` which resolved the issue of opening the browser in the local language.

NCR stands for NoCountryRedirect.